# Default background image on iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, delegates

Is there a way to set a default background image of the whole application in AppDelegate just like you set a default background for the navigation bar?

Example:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar.jpg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

At the moment I have this code on all my View Controllers:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
UIImageView *backgroundImageVIew = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
self.myTable.backgroundView = backgroundImageVIew;
```

I tried this in AppDelegate:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
UIImageView *backgroundImageVIew = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundView:backgroundImageVIew];
```

It works fine on all views except the ones I segue to. When I press a Table View Cell to segue to another view the application freezes and the CPU goes up to 100%.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using a navigation controller you can set the background image for the navigation controller.

Comment: You can consider add a sub class for UIViewController. I'm not sure. Do you need to have a try?

Comment: I would really like to get it working in AppDelegate. It feels like it should be possible. Just haven't figured out a way yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the following code in AppDelegates `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, 64.0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
[window addSubview:imageView];
```

The value 64.0 in the Y-frame is for pushing the imageView just below the status bar and the navigation bar (20 + 44).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom subclass of UINavigationController in which your pushViewController method looks something like

```
    -(void) pushViewController:(UIViewController*) vc animated:(BOOL) animated
    {
            UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
            UIImageView *backgroundImageVIew = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
            vc.backgroundView = backgroundImageVIew;
            [super pushViewController:vc animated:animated];
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, thought of that and got it working. But my question was if it's possible doing this in AppDelegate? I want to avoid subclasses. But if there is no alternative you answer is the best so far.